# Netbeans 7.0.1 internal terminal doesn't work using scanf

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int x;
    printf ("Enter integer: ");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    printf ("You entered %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using netbeans 7.0.1 with this version of mingw:

```
MINGWBASEDIR=C:\MinGW
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.21.53.20110804
GNU windres (GNU Binutils) 2.21.53.20110804
GNU dlltool (GNU Binutils) 2.21.53.20110804
GNU Make 3.82
#define __MINGW32_VERSION           3.20
#define __W32API_VERSION 3.17
```

I have problem runing c console applications in netbeans internal terminal (which is set default by netbeans). When my program have scanf function and I want to run my project, it just keep on processing until I kill it. If I don't use scanf in my code internal terminal works. External terminal works fine but I have to set external terminal in project properties for every project.

Comment: Description: The Standard Output console type is not used for debugging on Windows platform. 

Workaround: Use the Internal Terminal in the CYGWIN environment and the External Terminal in the MSYS environment instead.

Comment: You can/should add you comment as an answer and then mark the answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution and be able to easily locate it.