# Cannot enter value from netbeans but working in cmd

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw

I have installed MinGW on netbeans for C and C++ programming.
Here is a simple code that I am trying to run on netbeans :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Inside Main...\n");
    int n;
    printf("Enter : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);  // When I remove this line, it is working.
    printf("You have entered %d.", n);
    return (1);
}
```

Whenever I try to access any value from netbeans console, I don't see anything.

**Output with scanf(...)**

[image]

**Output without scanf(...)**

[image]

*And if I try to run these code from cmd, all are working*

Comment: I am not sure try adding `\n` after `printf"Enter..\n");`

Comment: I'm not sure too, but you could try `fflush(stdout));`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programs with the scanf not working properly in NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116958/programs-with-the-scanf-not-working-properly-in-netbeans)

Comment: Try to return 0 at the end. Otherwise go to project properties then to run at the bottom and change the console type from internal terminal to external terminal

Comment: @Gopi adding `\n` is not working.

Comment: @Rizier123 Netbeans doesn't support external console for MinGW

Comment: @afzalex Did you looked at the possible duplicate?

Comment: @cursillosonline adding `fflush(...)` after `printf("Enter : ");` is showing output upto this code but still cannot accepting any value.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8173558/3933332 (Read the first comment)

Comment: Did you solved the problem yet?

Comment: @Rizier123 No, not yet. And now I am supposing that there is no way to enter value in netbeans with mingw through its console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `scanf()` you must use `Netbeans External Terminal` !

[image]

Normal Run

[image]

You can also use `Netbeans Standard Output` !
But this is more misleading.
While you see an empty Terminal do input `123`

[image]

after hit enter , you get the output all at once .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while running a CPP program.External output didn't helped me. I set the console type to Standard output and it solved the issue.

Right Click cpp Application-->properties-->run--->Consoletype to standard output